# Use order by DESC and ASC with Group By

Tags: mysql

Here is my sql statement

```
 SELECT DISTINCT article_categories.category_id, 
   article_id,article_title,article_intro,article_content,
   category_name_ar 
 FROM articles,article_categories 
 WHERE articles.category_id=article_categories.category_id 
   AND article_type='admin' 
   AND category_case='active' 
 GROUP BY article_categories.category_id 
 ORDER BY article_categories.category_id ASC,
          article_date,article_time DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

I would like to retrieve the first DISTINCT 10 categories. In addition I would like to retrieve the equivalent articles where the articles.category_id equals article_categories.category_id. So far the result is good but what I am looking for is to order the result by category_id and in the same time order the result by the article_date,article_time DESC.

Any assistance will be appreciated in advance

Comment: if i understand you need : .... article_date DESC,article_time DESC ?

Comment: Right, and in the same time article_categories.category_id ASC, is that clear for you?

Comment: To make it more clearer, I would like to order the result by the category_id ASC. Furthermore, I would like to get the last added article under each category by using article_date DESC,article_time DESC

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT distinct c.category_id,...  
FROM articles a,article_categories c
WHERE a.category_id=c.category_id   
AND ...  
AND a.article_id in   
(SELECT max(a1.article_id)   
 FROM articles a1
 WHERE a1.category_id=c.category_id )
ORDER BY c.category_id ASC
```

Please replace ... with additional fields and conditions you need.

Comment: I have to use group by because it keeps repeat the category_name_ar, which I don't need. What I am looking for is the first ten article_categories ordered by the the category_id. Furthermore, the last added article under each category

Comment: 1. The fact that your query does not return what you expect does not imply that it should be resolved by group by.  
2. Order by cannot be used for getting latest records.
One more question: do you increment article_id from record to record?

Answer (score 1):

I got it

```
SELECT DISTINCT article_categories.category_id, 
   article_id,article_title,article_intro,article_content,
   category_name_ar 
 FROM articles,article_categories 
 WHERE articles.category_id=article_categories.category_id 
   AND article_type='admin' 
   AND category_case='active' 
 ORDER BY article_categories.category_id ASC,
          article_date desc,article_time DESC 
 LIMIT 10
```

Thanks all of your advises, it helped alot

Answer (score 0):

only add **desc** like

```
ORDER BY article_categories.category_id ASC,
          article_date DESC,article_time DESC
```